# 'assert_not user.valid?' vs. 'assert user.invalid?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm going through the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, and in 6.2.2 UserTest contains a test for 'name should be present'.  The test includes the code

```
test 'email should be present' do
  @user.email = "   "    
  assert_not user.valid?
end
```

and when the test fails, the following is output:

```
FAIL["test_name_should_be_present", UserTest, 0.10366088798036799]
 test_name_should_be_present#UserTest (0.10s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
```

If I change the assert to

```
test 'email should be present' do
  @user.email = "   "
  assert user.invalid?
end
```

the failing test output is

```
 FAIL["test_name_should_be_present", UserTest, 0.11991263600066304]
 test_name_should_be_present#UserTest (0.12s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
```

Are there situations in which one test would fail and not the other, or are these interchangeable?  'assert .invalid?' seems more natural to me.

BTW, the test fails because the test is written before the code to validate the presence of an email is written.

Comment: Would you please show the complete code from your tests?

Comment: There's also `refute user.valid?`, but I have mixed feelings about this one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

[.valid?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1335959135b908c284e4d7179e9d8c1261f0ee95/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L63) and invalid? will give you true or false, while [assert_not](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_not) expects nil or false and assert will expect a non-nil object or true.

Suppose the @user is invalid, then you can:

```
assert_not @user.valid? 
#valid will give you false, so 'assert_not false' is true, and the test passes.
```

on the other hand:

```
assert @user.invalid? 
#invalid will give you true, so 'assert true' is true, and the test passes.
```

You can do the same reasoning if we change hypothesis and @user is valid.